# Foreign characters - saving to database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have words like this in my fields:

```
Überblick
```

When I save them to the database it becomes:

```
Ãberblick
```

I have tried:

```
htmlspecialchars
$db->escape
mysql_real_escape_string
```

What is the correct solution to saving this to a mysql database using PHP?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do the following, after initialising the connection: `mysqli_set_charset("utf8");`